# HP ProCurve Preventing Loops and Users Plugging in Unauthorized Switches/Access-Points

Tags: switch, hp-procurve, spanning-tree

We have a `HP ProCurve 2530-24-PoE (J9773A)` switch, recently I had a user who plugged in an Apple wireless hardware device to the network - whenever it was connected I got a ton of broadcast warnings from the switch, intermittent bouts of packet loss and switch CPU usage went through the roof.

I removed his device and all is fine... given the entire office went down and no body could work every time it was plugged in I wasn't able to find the root cause other than something to do with the Apple hardware config. I can only assume he has setup as a client bridge to connect to the WiFi and caused a loop back via the Apple Ethernet port!

I have spanning-tree enabled on the HP ProCurve, but this didn't stop the network going down.

I am looking at stopping this happening again (and further more lock users from connecting their own unauthorized access-points/switches to the network) and seen the following recommended commands to harden against loops here https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/cscf/reports/CNAG/2009/ProCurve%20Best%20Practices.pdf:

```
loop-protect 1-24
spanning-tree 1-24 root-guard
spanning-tree 1-24 bpdu-protection
spanning-tree 1-24 admin-edge-port
loop-protect 1-24
```

**Question 1** - Can one sleep easy at night with those commands or anything I should be aware with the above?

**Question 2** - Will the above commands stop people messing with the network and connecting their own hardware, or are any other commands needed?

**Question 3** - If we have our own authorized wireless devices, would `bpdu-protection` stop the bridging of clients on the wireless access point, and should we leave this off on the ports that are connected to our wireless access points?

**Question 4** - We have a voice VLAN setup and specified as voice:

```
vlan 69
   name "DATA_VLAN"
   untagged 1-24
   no ip address
   exit
vlan 70
   name "VOICE_VLAN"
   tagged 1-24
   no ip address
   qos dscp 101110
   voice
   exit
```

The phones plug in to the switch, and computers to the back of the phone. Similair to question 3, how will `bpdu-protection` affect the fact I have a PC behind each phone (so essentially 2 MAC addresses per port). Does the fact the `voice` is specified in the voice vlan 70 allow for and take care of this?

Comment: Do you want to share the actual model of your HP Switch?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply it's a 2530-24-PoE, I have updated the question with this info

Comment: Can also start using Web and MAC Authentication to provide port based security to deny or give limited access to unknown devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a combination of `spanning-tree` commands and HP `loop-protect`:

```
loop-protect 1-44
spanning-tree
spanning-tree bpdu-protection-timeout 600 priority 1
spanning-tree 1-44 admin-edge-port
spanning-tree 1-44 bpdu-protection
```

I only did this for the edge ports, anything connected to other switches (in my case on ports 45-48) were left as default (without spanning tree or loop protect commands).